# Angular momentum about a point or angular momentum about an axis?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, reference-frames

What is the difference between the definition of angular momentum about a point as $\vec L=\vec r\times \vec p$ and that about an axis? How are they related? Can someone explain when the first second definition is useful and when the second is useful and why?

Comment: What is this "second definition" - you didn't actually write down any? Where have you seen a definition of angular momentum *about an axis*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of confusion in the comments.

- Angular momentum is *always* defined with respect to a point of reference, not an axis.
- The motion of a single rigid body may be described by an angular velocity, which does not depend on a point of reference.
- Both angular momentum and angular velocity are vectors (or technically pseudovectors, though this has no bearing on the rest of the question). They are related by $\vec{L} = I \vec{\omega}$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia tensor. They are not necessarily parallel.
- When we talk about "the axis of rotation of a rigid body", we *always* mean the direction of the angular velocity, not the direction of the angular momentum.
- In very basic introductory physics courses, you will usually only consider rigid bodies with an axis of symmetry, rotating about that axis. In that case, the directions of $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{\omega}$ both coincide with that axis of symmetry, so sometimes people talk about "the angular momentum about that axis". But it's not a sensible concept in general, because the angular momentum is usually not even parallel to the axis of rotation.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it's sometimes useful to separately consider the conservation of different components of the angular momentum vector. The component ${\bf L} \cdot \hat{\bf n}$ of ${\bf L}$ in the $\hat{\bf n}$ direction could be loosely thought of as "the angular momentum about the $\hat{\bf n}$ axis" - but as you say, you need to be careful because this doesn't necessarily correspond to an axis of rotation.

Comment: It's perfectly sensible to talk of angular momentum around an axis: it's a scalar that multiplies the axial vector representing the axis. The angular momentum about a point is an axial vector.

Comment: @JohnDoty Are you proposing to define the angular momentum as $|\vec{L}| \, \vec{\omega} / \, |\vec{\omega}|$, then? That's certainly something you can define, but it's not what many would call angular momentum (for instance, it's not conserved in rigid body motion).

Comment: @knzhou When I say "axis" I don't mean "axis of rotation".

Comment: "Both angular momentum and angular velocity are vectors" No, they're members of Clifford algebras.

Comment: Angular velocity and angular momentum are  not vectors, rather they are pseudovectors (cf., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector)