# About the coincidence of angular momentum and angular velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Let me quote part of the answer by @knzhou , posted [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/704255/164488)

> "In very basic introductory physics courses, you will usually only consider rigid bodies with an axis of symmetry, rotating about that axis. In that case, the directions of $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{\omega}$ both coincide with that axis of symmetry, so sometimes people talk about "the angular momentum about that axis". But it's not a sensible concept in general, because the angular momentum is usually not even parallel to the axis of rotation."

Consider a cylinder that is rotating about its axis with a uniform angular velocity $\vec{\omega}=\omega\hat{z}$. Starting from the definition of angular momentum about any point on this axis, we can write, $$\vec{L}=\sum_im_i\vec{r}_i\times(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_i)=\sum_im_i[r_i^2\vec{\omega} -{\vec r}_i({\vec r}_i\cdot\vec{\omega})].$$ With $\omega_x=\omega_y=0$ and $\omega_z=\omega\neq 0$, we can see that $L_x,L_y\neq 0$ in addition to $L_z\neq 0$. Therefore, $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{\omega}$ do not coincide. Did I misunderstand something in the quotation? The axis of the cylinder is an axis of symmetry, I believe.

Comment: The issue is that you did not use the assumption that your object is a cylinder. While individual terms have $x,y$ components, from symmetry arguments, the sum does not. Check out the concept of principle axis of inertia.